# Why does grep -w take a lot longer than grep?

Tags: unix, grep

Why does `grep -w` take so much longer than a simple `grep`?

Comment: @cad I don't think there is need to show input, since it is a more generic question.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -w` matches whole words, not just 'hits' like the normal `grep`. This is achieved by applying regular expressions on the input. Regular expressions are by nature a really expensive technique and should always be used with caution.